# Android NDK - static analysis for native c++ code

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Is there a static analysis tool integrated into the Android NDK for native code?  From my understanding, it looks like the NDK recently transitioned to CLang which I think has a built-in static analyzer (https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html), but I can't seem to find out how to use it.  I am guessing I just need to update my CMake file somehow?

I searched through all the gradle tasks using "./gradlew tasks --all" and I saw the "externalNativeBuild" task but that just builds the native source code.

Ideally, I would like to just run a single command/task and an output file is generated with all the static analysis issues for my native code -- similar to Java's "lint" task where an HTML file is created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you have an integrated tool for that in Android Studio. However, you can also try [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/). It is not perfect, but it is not bad at all and saved me in several occasions. You can use it for single files or build a project once and load it each time. It is also free.

Comment: Is there a simple way to integrate it into an Android project ?

Comment: No, it is an external tool. What I used to do was to created a 'project' for it once, keep it with my source files, and every once in a while double click it and run the check. Not ideal, but effective with no hassle.